# Is it possible to create unit tests for functions that use Xamarin.Essentials: Geolocation API?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin, xunit, xamarin.essentials

In my `Locationer` class I have function `GetLocationAsync()` which uses Xamarin.Essentials: Geolocation. This function works fine but I would like to create unit test for this function.

I created xUnitTests project and unit test:

```
public async Task LocationTest()
{
    Locationer locationer = new Locationer();
    var actual = locationer.GetLocationAsync();

    Assert.Equal("test", actual);
}
```

In Xamarin Forms project `GetLocationAsync()` returns "Latitude: 46.55465, Longitude: 15.64588, Altitude: 262".

In my unit tests `GetLocationAsync()` returns "This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly"

Is it possible to use Xamarin.Essentials: Geolocation in my Unit Tests project? How can I fix it?

Comment: I would suggest abstracting out that implementation concern.

Answer (score 6):

Ryan Davis has created interfaces based on Xamarin.Essentials: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Essentials.Interfaces/

This way you can register Essentials implementations in your IoC container:

```
builder.Register<IGeolocation, GeolocationImplementation>();
```

And you would be able to Mock the interfaces with something like Moq:

```
var mockGeo = new Mock<IGeolocation>();
mockGeo.Setup(x => x.GetLocationAsync())
   .ReturnsAsync(() => new Location());
```

Comment: wow, I haven't heard anything about IoC containers and mocking before so I have to read something about it asap. Thank you for help. I hope it will work. Last question: Should I implement "builder" and "mockGeo" inside mobile app project or inside unit tests project?